# How do you do a global search and replace in all the files in Delphi 2006 project

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

I'm trying to do a global search and replace in all the files in Delphi 2006 project, but am unable to do so.

How can I do this?

Comment: DELPHI 2010 has the same problem

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know no such feature exists in D2006.

I use Notepad++ for that task.

Comment: across multiple modules? i.e. global

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the Rename option in the Refactoring menu. It works on multiple files.

Comment: I find it frequently misses references and I have to rename them with the editor anyway.

Answer (score -1):

GEExperts works very well on Delphi 7. Do a global search in the grep of GEExperts, then click "Replace". Pretty straightforward. Integrates directly into the IDE too.

Answer (score -1):

To search all the files in your project you can use:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Comment: Unfortunately this only searches for a expression; it does not allow a replace in all found occurrences.